# Python Unittest fails if all tests are run, but each passes individually

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I created a Unittest for an ETL process with SQLAlchemy as an ORM.
The testfile is in the "test" folder and is called "test_static_basics.py"
I have a setUp-, and tearDown method in place  where I establish the database connection, create the tables, fill them with some initial data and finaly drop all tables to have a clean set up for the next test... in theory.
I added some code excerpts but tried to limit the amount of code you have to read. But I gladly extend the example if requested.

```
class Test_import_static_tables(unittest.TestCase):  
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.mssql_db = MSSQLHandler(server='localhost',database="unit_test",sql_echo=False)
        # in case the test crashes, drop first
        self.mssql_db.drop_tables()
        # then reinit
        self.mssql_db.create_tables()
        self.create_system_from_bundle()
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.mssql_db.drop_tables()

    def create_system_from_bundle(self):
        with self.mssql_db.session_scope() as session: #the scope commits after yielding the session
            bundle = SystemBundle(bundle_dict={'dictionized':'test_data'})
            session.merge(bundle)
            session.commit()
            bundle_dict={'more_dictionized':'test_data'}
            system=System(bundle_dict=bundle_dict,bundle=bundle)
            session.merge(system)

    def test_creation_from_bundle(self):
        session=self.mssql_db.session_maker()
        system=session.query(System).filter(System.sid=='sid_1').first()
        self.assert_some_tests(...)
```

So when I run each test by itself ([run tests individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFnHN.png) they all pass as expected.
The setUp is called, the tables are created at my db and filled with some sample data and then tested against and the tests pass.
When I run all of them ([Run all tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iygp.gif)), the failing test throws an error in the setUp method but only the the third time its called. What I really dont get is why it passes the first two time.
It seems that there are some states set in some tests and persisted to the others but since I test on the nuked database this should be impossible.
I get the same results if I call the test with `python -m unittest test/test_static_basics.py`.
I hope I just did something extremly stupid which you spot out directly!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well it was something stupid but still very unexpected behaviour of the unittest.
I had a bug in the setUp method which was inside a try: except Block. So it didn't blew directly in my face.
The only real issue I still have is that the unittest didn't had a problem with the same function the first two times and reported the tests as succeses.
I'm quite positive that thats not the desired behaviour of the unittest package. Do you agree and if so where would you post the issue so that other people don't get in the same mess?